# How to send a single pipelined command to python using bash from a groovy script console (Jenkins)?

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, groovy, pipe

I am using the groovy script console as offered by Jenkins.
I have this nicely working line for a Jenkins slave (Windows based):

```
println "cmd /c echo print(\"this is a sample text.\") | python".execute().text
```

Now i want the functional equivalent for a Jenkins slave (Linux based).
So i started on the Linux command line and got this core command working for me:

```
bash -c 'echo print\(\"this is a sample text.\"\) | python'
```

Then i wrapped all of this console command line into a some more escape codes  and invocation decoration - but by this it went to a no longer functional state:

```
println "bash -c \'echo print\\(\\\"this is a sample text.\\\"\\) | python\'".execute().txt
```

The result when running it is just this:

*empty*

I feel i am stuck at the moment due failing to solve the multitude of effecting escape character levels.
Whats wrong? How to solve it? (And maybe: why?)

PS: if unclear - i want (if possible at all) to stick to an one-liner as the initial item was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to pipe bash into python, maybe this suits your fancy?

```
['python','-c','print("this is a sample text")'].execute().text
```

If you *do* need it, try

```
['bash','-c', /echo print\(\"this is a sample text.\"\) | python/].execute().text
```

Using `List`'s `.execute()` helps with clarifying what each argument is. The slashy-strings help by changing the escape-character.

Comment: the first item does not create any output; the second item is working in the scripting console but has a leading tag "Result: " - combining the commands with a initial println creates scripting errors. ---

println "test 1:"
['python','-c','print("this is a sample text")'].execute().text
println "test 2:"
['bash','-c', /echo print\(\"this is a sample text.\"\) | python/].execute().text
test 1:
test 2:
Result: this is a sample text.

Comment: thanks to thehole for providing the two key elements: * using lists is totally valid and helps much in command line argument separation; * using alternate quotation characters reduces needed rate for escape characters to a manageable/maintainable level.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get output with the first: `groovy:000> ['python','-c','print("this is a sample text")'].execute().text
===> this is a sample text`

Comment: me was surprised too. maybe its the way the output is taking... and thus it will not find the right catch for Jenkins console to web connection. only aliasing it with a symbol name and then executing it in a println context worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "bash -c 'echo \"print(\\\"this is a sample text.\\\")\" | python'"
```

Output:

```
bash -c 'echo "print(\"this is a sample text.\")" | python'
```

Comment: when adding ".execute().text" it wont print anything for me.
but the incremental approach sounds very promising because it inserts a check layer before the final execution. - i previousely found escapes for the round braces might be something i should look at.

Comment: not working with even those further stripped variant:
println "bash -c 'echo \"print(\\\"this is a sample text.\\\")\"'".execute().text

(sorry, i dont get the keystone of the problem for now.

Comment: maybe the extra term "from a grovy script console" in the headline was not considered in this answer. the middle term iteration indeed used pure bash as a helper, so this is still contributing in terms of verifying the results of the taken measures at least up to an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for some more while i found a somewhat platform-independent, error channel (stderr) aware and execution fault capable solution that even avoids OS specific components like bash/cmd.exe:

```
try {
  def command = ['python', '-c', /print("this is a sample text.")/];
  if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows'))
  {
    command[2] = command[2].replaceAll(/\"/, /\\\"/)
  }
  println "command=" + command
  def proc = command.execute()
  def rc = proc.waitFor()
  println "rc=" + rc

  def err = proc.err.text
  if( err != "" ) { print "stderr=" + err }

  def out = proc.text
  if( out != "" ) { print "stdout=" + out }
} catch(Exception e) {
  println "exception=" + e
}
println ""
```

Comment: under the hood cmd.exe might still be in there - because the double-quotes are needing escaping. its assumed that some cmd.exe parsing still takes place under the hood rather then the runtime environment doing some sort of an "exec()" on the system/c-api level.